# Apply style of back button to the right button react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add a `Right Button` in the `StackNavigators` Header.
[Looking at this example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#adding-a-button-to-the-header) ( I modified it) it is rather easy with `react-navigation`

```
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Text>
              Foo
            </Text>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to apply the system specific style to the `right button`.

[According to the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#customizing-the-back-button)

> Customizing the back button

> createStackNavigator provides the platform-specific defaults for the back button. On iOS this includes a label next to the button, which shows the title of the previous screen when the title fits in the available space, otherwise it says "Back".

There is somewhere a style applied for the `left button`. Can I somehow use this style and apply it to the `right button`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a community driven Library taking care of this
https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons